# Ionic: Remove view from cache dynamically

Tags: javascript, angular, caching, ionic-framework

I have a view that uses one way bindings. If I refresh the data from another view or do pull to refresh, the one way bindings models don't update. Is it possible to force the view to reload before navigating to it or refreshing it? I'm not asking about cache: false in the router or cache-view="false" at that page level. I do want those views to be cached. But I want to force them to reload as if they were not in the dom when their data changes from another view. I tried $ionicHistory.clearCache(['some-view-name']).then(... But it didn't work.

Comment: Is this a form, or some sort of display mode only thing. Not enough to go on.

Comment: I don't think it matters. The question is to dynamically kick a view from the cache and the dom as if it had never been visted previously.

Comment: Well the reason I was trying to determine if it related to a form was the pristine property https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#inspect-formcontrol-properties - but I suspect you are inferring something else..